# Reddit API token generation via http post call

Tags: java, reddit

I'm trying to get a token for the reddit api using java. There are a ton of examples out there using Python so I figured I'd simply translate one to java. Clearly that wasn't so simple.

This is the java code

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token");
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("CLIENT ID", "API SECRET KEY");
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<>(3);
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "MY USERNAME"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "MY PASSWORD"));

    StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(URLEncodedUtils.format(nvps, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    httppost.setEntity(strEntity);
    httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", "MyBot/0.0.1");

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
            .build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost)) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

This results in a 5xx server error, which you can see below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comparing this with the Python version

```
import requests

auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('CLIENT ID', 'API SECRET KEY')

data = {'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': 'MY USERNAME',
        'password': 'MY PASSWORD'}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'MyBot/0.0.1'}

res = requests.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',
                    auth=auth, data=data, headers=headers)

TOKEN = res.json()['access_token']

headers = {**headers, **{'Authorization': f"bearer {TOKEN}"}}


requests.get('https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me', headers=headers)
```

Results in a completed request with the token.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the entire 500 response and the actual JSON you are posting.

Comment: @tgdavies I've edited the question and added the response. I'm not posting any json, the header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the entity from:

```
StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(URLEncodedUtils.format(nvps, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
```

To

```
StringEntity strEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

And after long time no use HttpClient, I know why I've switched to okHttp